# Windows - Removing keyboard-related messages from message queue

Tags: c++, c, windows, keyboard, message

I need to remove all keyboard-related messages from the message queue of a thread. After some researches i managed to write the following code :

```
for( MSG zMsg; PeekMessage( & zMsg, NULL, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE ); );
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I don't know if this is a good practice or not but i don't have the possibility and the time to rewrite the code i'm working on to make it cleaner.

How could i get this code to work please ?

Thanks for your help !

EDIT : I'm using WindowsCE

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? It looks ok to me.

Comment: Because once i reach what comes after, keys are sent. I've added a ::MessageBox() call in the 3rd part of the for loop to make sure it finds at least one message, but no pop-up show up. Am i using the wrong filters maybe ?

Comment: I think i found the cause. WindowsCE doesn't handle default value (NULL) for the window handle parameter.

Comment: Interesting. I'm impressed anyone is still using WindowsCE, to be honest :)

Comment: @Jonathan Potter The client wants what the client wants :)

Comment: I'm using a virtual box and the shared clipboard wasn't working so i rewrote the code manually. It still doesn't work no matter what hWnd i put into it though, i tried GetFocus(), i tried GetActiveWindow(), i tried -1, none worked :( EDIT : And no there is no syntax error ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you are filtering everything except keyboard messages.

```
wMsgFilterMin
```

The value of the first message in the range of messages to be examined.

```
wMsgFilterMax
```

The value of the last message in the range of messages to be examined.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: `WM_KEYFIRST` is the lowest value keyboard-related message, and `WM_KEYLAST` is the highest value keyboard-related message.

Comment: Yes, that's what i want, select each keyboard message to remove it.

Comment: Peekmessage returns `false` if there are no messages in the queue. Try `while(1) { PeekMessage( & zMsg, NULL, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE ); }`

Comment: @Prownage When do you think that loop will terminate?

Comment: @AlanStokes The for loop ends if there are no more messages in the queue. The while loop will never end.

Comment: @AlanStokes Depends on what the goal of your application is.

Comment: I need it to clean all the keyboard messages that are present in the queue at the moment of the call, further messages must not be deleted.

Comment: Maybe while(PeekMessage(...));